# how to open a file using exec method in java?

Tags: java, runtime.exec

```
C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\VID_20160226_203631957.mp4
```

when I execute above line in command prompt the corresponding video gets played with default media player.

But when I try to do same using java Runtime class it doesnt work.
I am using following method.

```
Runtime r= Runtime.getRuntime();
r.exec("C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\VID_20160226_203631957.mp4")
```

Comment: in Windows try to use command `start C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\VID_20160226_203631957.mp4`. If filename contains spaces use double quotes for your file path. For example: if your file name is `my file.mp4` then use the command: `start "my file.mp4"`

Comment: Do not use runtime exec. Use Process Builder https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: @Hector You should create an answer for that. It's the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Runtime r= Runtime.getRuntime();
r.exec("cmd /c C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\VID_20160226_203631957.mp4");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Desktop.open(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open-java.io.File-) which *launches the associated application to open the file.* Something like,

```
File f = new File("C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/VID_20160226_203631957.mp4");
try {
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You might prefer to build the path relative to the [user's home directory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html); something like

```
File downloads = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Downloads");
File f = new File(downloads, "VID_20160226_203631957.mp4");
```